# Best way to load modules node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

My project has got many folders and I often load my own modules in node.js in the following way:

```
var request = require("request"),
    config  = require("../../../modules/config"),
    urls    = require("../../../modules/urls");
```

I sometimes move the folders around and the path changes, so I need to adjust the `../` part manually.

I don't want to move my modules into the node_modules folder, but I'd like to load the modules in the following way:

```
var request = require("request"),
    config  = require("config"),
    urls    = require("urls");
```

or

```
var request = require("request"),
    config  = require("modules/config"),
    urls    = require("modules/urls");
```

What are my options?

Comment: you could run your own private npm and register them there...? http://clock.co.uk/tech-blogs/how-to-create-a-private-npmjs-repository

Comment: these modules are mostly project specific

Comment: if a module inside a folder requires a module upper in the folder hierarchy,it's a strong sign that your code smells and should be refactored to makes the modules less coupled.

Comment: as an example - my routes module uses the urls module to get all the urls in the system and set the links correctly in the rendered html, so I don't think you are 100% right

Comment: just put it in `node_modules`, nothing wrong with that

Comment: I don't want to keep my modules with vendor modules in one place, I ignore the node_modules folder in the .gitignore file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New Answer:**

Relative paths seem to be the simplest choice after all, it allows you to run your script from any location.

```
var config = require("../../config");
```

**Old answer:**

I found out that, while not ideal, there's also the possibility to use `process.cwd()`.

```
var request = require("request"),
    config  = require(process.cwd() + "/modules/config");
```

or, if the process.cwd() is set to a global variable in the main js file

```
global.cwd = process.cwd();
```

then

```
var request = require("request"),
    config  = require(global.cwd + "/modules/config"),
    urls    = require(global.cwd + "/modules/urls");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do the following, based on some conditions

- if the scripts are exclusively written for your application, meaning it won't work with any other application, and the scripts **don't** have any dependencies place them under `modules` directory and try to create expose a variable such as `global.basepath` and using `path.join` to construct the filepath and require it.You could also inject module variable after you require them at the main script of your app.

`main.js`

```
var config = require('modules/config.js')(_,mongoose,app);
```

`modules/config.js`

```
module.exports=function(_,mongoose,app){
 return function(){
  // _,mongoose,app
  this.loadConfigVariable..
 }
}
```

- if the scripts are not one-files that have separate tests, require other vendor modules in order to be executed then create individual node modules and publish them to a registry for convenience when installing the main application.
  Just as express does, there is the main application `express` and there are modules that `express` uses such as `express-validation` which in turn has its own dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a symlink in `node_modules`, pointing to wherever your modules are.

For example, add a symlink named "my_modules", referencing '../foo/bar/my_modules'. Then, your requires will look like

```
var config = require('my_modules/config');
var urls = require('my_modules/urls');
```